# c++ parameter pack expansion with concepts

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, template-meta-programming

Why I get a compilation error if uncomment line #1 and comment line #2?
Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/KW6dhsrKd

```
#include <utility>

template <typename, std::size_t> concept prefix = true;

template<std::size_t>
struct dummy { template<typename T> constexpr dummy(T){}; };

template <auto N>
consteval auto nth_element(auto... args) 
{
return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    //return [](prefix<Is> auto..., auto arg, auto...) { //compile error // #1
    return [](dummy<Is> ..., auto arg, auto...) { // OK                  // #2
    return arg;
    }(args...);
}(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(nth_element<0>(1, 2, 3) == 1);
    static_assert(nth_element<1>(1, 2, 3) == 2);
    static_assert(nth_element<2>(1, 2, 3) == 3);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The #1 form introduces a new parameter pack, whereas #2 expands an already existing pack.

Comment: A concept itself cannot represent a type, only constraints on a type. Not the the whole body of `nth_element` can be replaced by `return std::get<N>(std::tuple{args...});`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [[dcl.fct]/22](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.fct-22):

> An abbreviated function template is equivalent to a function template ([temp.fct]) whose *template-parameter-list* includes one invented type *template-parameter* for each generic parameter type placeholder of the function declaration, in order of appearance. [..] The invented type *template-parameter* is a template parameter pack if the corresponding *parameter-declaration* declares a function parameter pack.

Note that `prefix<Is> auto...` is both a pack and a pack expansion simultaneously.
So the transformed template would look like

```
[] <prefix<Is>... Args> (Args..., auto arg, auto...) {
    return arg;
}(args...)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
[] <typename... Args> requires(prefix<Args, Is> && ...) (Args..., auto arg, auto...) {
    return arg;
}(args...)
```

<sup>(This still [generates the same error message](https://godbolt.org/z/TsnG81s7z), too.)</sup>
Where we can see that 1) Args is [in a non-deduced context](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.type#5.7) and will [always remain empty](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#1.sentence-7), and 2) `Is`  and `Args` would have to [agree in length](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#variadic-7.sentence-4) for the constraint to be satisfiable.

The solution given in the comments is not ideal IMO, as creating a tuple is likely relatively expensive (especially at compile time). I think your solution + proper forwarding is the best for now (until we get [proper pack subscripts](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1858r2.html)). I.e. something like this:

```
template<std::size_t>
struct dummy { constexpr dummy(auto&&){}; };

template <std::size_t N, typename... Args>
constexpr decltype(auto) nth_element(Args&&... args) {
    return [&]<std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) -> decltype(auto) {
        return [](dummy<Is> ..., auto&& arg, auto&&...) -> decltype(auto) { // OK                  // #2
            return std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg);
        }(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```